# Projection that keeps graviton but gets rid of B-field

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, quantization

We consider the closed superstring and the massless states in the (NS,NS)-sector
\begin{equation}
\tilde{b}^i_{-\frac{1}{2}} |0\rangle_L \otimes b^j_{-\frac{1}{2}} |0\rangle_R.
\end{equation} 
It is known that these 64 states contain the graviton (taking symmetric traceless linear combinations), the $B$-field (antisymmetric combinations) and the dilaton (trace). Of course the fermion number for all these states is the same, so it is not possible to use a GSO projection to get rid of the $B$-field while keeping the graviton.

Is it possible to take another projection that keeps the graviton while removing the $B$-field?